# Calling Javascript Function in wordpress menu

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

in my `html` website I can call any `javascript` function through anchor like this

```
<a href="javascript:function();"></a>
```

but when I try to add this in `wordpress` menu option then after saving menu , everything vanished from there and field becomes empty. how can I call functions through `wordpress` Menu's.

any one can help please ?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say what the problem is without seeing your JS, but you could try this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a id="red" href="#" onclick="myFunction()">List Item with Function</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List Item without Function</a></li>
</ul>

function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById('red').setAttribute('style', 'color: red');
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BSshG/1/

Or handle the click even with JavaScript and don't worry about changing the HTML:

```
document.getElementById('red').onclick = function(){
    this.style.color = "red";
}
```

Another fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BSshG/2/

Comment: hey I donot have any issues in javascript , I just want to call those functions through wordpress own menu's that we created through GUI

Comment: Try using the `onclick` attribute on your `a` element to call your function, as I have done in my answer. If that doesn't work, the issue could be one either with Wordpress not loading your script (do a search for enqueueing scripts), or possibly with the way Wordpress is generating the HTML (for instance, you probably do not want to put the HTML in the WYSIWYG editor, but in the actual source).

Comment: how can I add onclick event there while there's only URL field in wordpress . 
you are not getting my point

Comment: Updated my answer with another option. If you don't know what the `id` of the `a` is, you can view the site in the browser, right-click on that element and choose "Inspect Element".